# Open find widget with content programatically in Monaco

Tags: monaco-editor

I can't figure out how to open the find widget with content in Monaco. From looking at some other extensions' code, it looks like I should do something like this:

```js
editor.trigger("find", "editor.actions.findWithArgs", { searchString: "test" })
```

While this opens the find widget, it doesn't change the search string. I tried other ways too, and while I could do something like this to set the content:

```js
const controller = editor.getContribution("editor.contrib.findController")
controller.setSearchString("test")
```

I would rather use .trigger, or at least understand why it doesn't work

Comment: The first line should work but believe it or not it's a 2 years bug that's been fixed 2 hours ago https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2547 the payload was not passed to the action's run method https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/176504/files

Comment: wow, okay;  
feel free to make this an answer because it pretty much is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line should work but, believe it or not, it's a 2 years bug that's been fixed **yesterday**: [Can't access payload in action method](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2547)

The issue is the `payload` (so here `{ searchString: "test" }`) was simply not passed to the action's `run` method [Fixes https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2547 #176504](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/176504/files) as shown here:

[image: Fixes https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2547 #176504]

PS: The fix is not yet release in the downloadable version as of today.